# CView::OnFilePrint crashing MFC application

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

We have an MFC application that has been used and maintained for many years.  Recently we made some administrative changes to some computers that are running the application. Now the software occasionally crashes when printing from the application.

We are using pretty standard MFC code to initiate the printing. We added `try/catch` blocks around what we felt like are the pertinent areas of the code with no luck. Whatever is failing does not seem to throw.

We get the typical dialog stating that "____ MFC Application has stopped working". Closing the program is the only option.

The windows event logger shows that our application is the Faulting application.

The exception code is **0xc0000005**, which appears to be an **Access Denied** error.

The application is in the `CView::OnFilePrint()` code when the crash occurs.
We have added some logging, and we know that we get through `DoPreparePrinting`, and `OnBeginPrinting`.

We believe that `CDC::StartDoc` would be the next thing called, then `CView::OnPrepareDC`. We don't get to `OnPrepareDC` when we fail.

We don't seem to find the source code for `CView::OnFilePrint`, so we are not sure what it looks like.  From research online, we think that things happen in this order in `OnFilePrint`:

```
// what we think is in OnFilePrint:
CView::OnFilePrint()
{
    OnPreparePrinting();   <- we get through our override of this
    OnBeginPrinting();     <- we get through our override of this

    // loop back to here on multiple docs
    CDC::StartDoc();
    CView::OnPrepareDC();  <- we do not reach our override of this
    CView::OnPaint();
    CDC::EndPage();
    // loop back on multiple docs
    ...
    // finish if last doc...
}
```

I would like to have the source for it so we could attempt to rewrite it and try to gracefully fail instead of failing by crashing.

I'm looking for:

1) any suggestions as to how to figure out why the process of printing causes our application to crash.

2) A location for where the `CView::OnFilePrint` code is located, if available.
  (the only idea I have left to narrow down the problem is to call our own version of this so that we can step through it and add logging and/or see if we can at least fail gracefully when it the problem occurs.)

The printer is Xerox Phaser 3610, for what its worth.

Comment: Error code 5 translates to "Access denied". 0xC0000005 is an access violation. In other words: You are trying to access memory for which you do not have the requested access rights. This is usually caused by heap corruption, dangling pointers and the like. I.e. there's a bug in your code. The most promising way to diagnose the issue would be to dump the process state on unhandled exceptions. I believe you can use WER for that.

Comment: source code for `CView::OnFilePrint` should be in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\viewprnt.cpp`, depending on VS version. There could also be a problem with printer initialization/access.

Comment: What "you think" is in the code? That won't really be sufficient.  Where is the CDC created?  Why are you calling OnViewPrint() ??? That's wrong... Should be calling OnDraw() with the proper arguments.  Why can't you just build with symbols and attach a debugger and step through?

Comment: Bit of a stab in the dark but when I upgraded to Windows 10 I had to reinstall my printer drivers otherwise printing would fail.

Comment: @Joe Willcoxson - We haven't stumbled into the source - it is part of Microsoft's MFC - hence 2) A location for where CView::OnFilePrint is... Then I will know what the source is.  We are failing in Microsoft code, not in our code.  We are stepping through, but we end up in code with no debug info.  It doesn't fail often, so the chance of catching it while stepping through are also somewhat slim.

Comment: @Barmak Sherimani - Thank you, very helpful.  We found the CView class there, but didn't stumble in to viewprnt.cpp.  The source code I was after is in that file.  If you form that as an answer, I will accept it as a solution.

Comment: I had a similar problem before. Immediately after installation the application remained in Admin mode. The program crashed upon accessing printer. I had to make sure the program is not in admin mode (but I don't know why that matters! I also had bugs relating to uninitialized variable)

Comment: The fact that Microsoft's code throws an access violation is no indication, that the bug is in that code. After all, it's operating on arguments *you* supply. A random access violation really is a very strong indication for an issue with your code. It's screaming "undefined behavior", and you just ran out of luck when you made some changes to the environment. Set up WER to write a minidump on an unhandled exception, and analyze it in a debugger of your choice. That'll take you right to the pointer that has gone wayward.

Comment: Can you point me to sample code?  I looked through some stuff on Microsoft and some of their sample code links seem broke.

Comment: @IInspectable, I posted an answer that explains what we found.  We did end up adding the WER hook into the code, but we found the problem before we added the code.  We are leaving the WER code in place, because it looks like a very useful way to debug these kinds of situations. 
 Thanks for the tip.  It turns out that the OnFilePrint function is sensitive to what thread it is called on.  We had a worker thread that was occasionally executing the OnFilePrint instead of the main thread.  This crashes inside of the standard CView::OnFilePrint function.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't explicit on this one. You don't need any code changes to set up WER to trigger a minidump on unhandled exceptions (see [Collecting User-Mode Dumps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787181.aspx)). Anyway, it's strictly required, that all your `WM_PAINT` handling is performed on the thread that owns the window. I would also suggest that you accept your answer, because it appears to be more helpful to future visitors. The other answer addresses the question that's not part of the solution.

Comment: We added code that calls RegisterApplicationRecoveryCallback in our InitInstance, which works.  I wasn't familiar with WER at all, and didn't know it could be configured in the registry.  I simulated the error condition we had after we added the WER code, and the dump file would have taken us right to the offending null pointer.  We are leaving this in our applications for future issues.  I'm excited about what it will do for us.  Thanks again.  If I mark my answer, will it take the answer away from Bermak Shemarini?  He gave me what I asked for, which led me to the answer...

Comment: On another note, it seems like they would do some debug check on that pointer and give you an indication that you are on the wrong thread.  At least in debug builds.  They check for the CDC to be valid, and most other things, but not the hwnd.

Comment: *"If I mark my answer, will it take the answer away from Bermak Shemarini?"* Yes you can change it, thanks for asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside of CView::OnFilePrint, this occurs:

```
CWnd * hwndTemp = AfxGetMainWnd();
```

It turns out that if you don't call OnFilePrint from the main thread, this returns NULL.

Due to slight timing changes when the computers were logged onto a domain, OnFilePrint was being called from another thread.  This causes the above call to return null, then when this line gets executed:

```
hwndTemp->EnableWindow(FALSE);
```

The application crashes.

There are several ways to fix this.  One is to use this:

```
CWnd * hwndTemp = AfxGetApp()->GetMainWnd();
```

In place of this:

```
CWnd * hwndTemp = AfxGetMainWnd();
```

Another way is to assure that `OnFilePrint` is only called from the main thread.

A cut to the chase version of the code in CView::OnFilePrint is here:

```
    // disable main window while printing & init printing status dialog
    // Store the Handle of the Window in a temp so that it can be enabled 
    // once the printing is finished
    CWnd * hwndTemp = AfxGetMainWnd();      // <--- CAN RETURN NULL HERE
    hwndTemp->EnableWindow(FALSE);          // <--- CRASH WILL OCCUR HERE
    CPrintingDialog dlgPrintStatus(this);
```

Full version of CView::OnFilePrint is below.

The `OnFilePrint` code, with the problem area noted:

```
void CView::OnFilePrint()
{
    // get default print info
    CPrintInfo printInfo;
    ASSERT(printInfo.m_pPD != NULL);    // must be set

    if (LOWORD(GetCurrentMessage()->wParam) == ID_FILE_PRINT_DIRECT)
    {
        CCommandLineInfo* pCmdInfo = AfxGetApp()->m_pCmdInfo;

        if (pCmdInfo != NULL)
        {
            if (pCmdInfo->m_nShellCommand == CCommandLineInfo::FilePrintTo)
            {
                printInfo.m_pPD->m_pd.hDC = ::CreateDC(pCmdInfo->m_strDriverName,
                    pCmdInfo->m_strPrinterName, pCmdInfo->m_strPortName, NULL);
                if (printInfo.m_pPD->m_pd.hDC == NULL)
                {
                    AfxMessageBox(AFX_IDP_FAILED_TO_START_PRINT);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        printInfo.m_bDirect = TRUE;
    }

    if (OnPreparePrinting(&printInfo))
    {
        // hDC must be set (did you remember to call DoPreparePrinting?)
        ASSERT(printInfo.m_pPD->m_pd.hDC != NULL);

        // gather file to print to if print-to-file selected
        CString strOutput;
        if (printInfo.m_pPD->m_pd.Flags & PD_PRINTTOFILE && !printInfo.m_bDocObject)
        {
            // construct CFileDialog for browsing
            CString strDef(MAKEINTRESOURCE(AFX_IDS_PRINTDEFAULTEXT));
            CString strPrintDef(MAKEINTRESOURCE(AFX_IDS_PRINTDEFAULT));
            CString strFilter(MAKEINTRESOURCE(AFX_IDS_PRINTFILTER));
            CString strCaption(MAKEINTRESOURCE(AFX_IDS_PRINTCAPTION));
            CFileDialog dlg(FALSE, strDef, strPrintDef,
                OFN_HIDEREADONLY|OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT, strFilter, NULL, 0);
            dlg.m_ofn.lpstrTitle = strCaption;

            if (dlg.DoModal() != IDOK)
                return;

            // set output device to resulting path name
            strOutput = dlg.GetPathName();
        }

        // set up document info and start the document printing process
        CString strTitle;
        CDocument* pDoc = GetDocument();
        if (pDoc != NULL)
            strTitle = pDoc->GetTitle();
        else
            EnsureParentFrame()->GetWindowText(strTitle);
        DOCINFO docInfo;
        memset(&docInfo, 0, sizeof(DOCINFO));
        docInfo.cbSize = sizeof(DOCINFO);
        docInfo.lpszDocName = strTitle;
        CString strPortName;
        if (strOutput.IsEmpty())
        {
            docInfo.lpszOutput = NULL;
            strPortName = printInfo.m_pPD->GetPortName();
        }
        else
        {
            docInfo.lpszOutput = strOutput;
            AfxGetFileTitle(strOutput,
                strPortName.GetBuffer(_MAX_PATH), _MAX_PATH);
        }

        // setup the printing DC
        CDC dcPrint;
        if (!printInfo.m_bDocObject)
        {
            dcPrint.Attach(printInfo.m_pPD->m_pd.hDC);  // attach printer dc
            dcPrint.m_bPrinting = TRUE;
        }
        OnBeginPrinting(&dcPrint, &printInfo);

        if (!printInfo.m_bDocObject)
            dcPrint.SetAbortProc(_AfxAbortProc);

/**********************************************************************
    Problem area.

    If the calling thread is not the main thread, the call to AfxGetMainWnd
    can return NULL.  In this case, hwndTemp->EnableWindow(FALSE) will crash
    the application.
**********************************************************************/

        // disable main window while printing & init printing status dialog
        // Store the Handle of the Window in a temp so that it can be enabled 
        // once the printing is finished
        CWnd * hwndTemp = AfxGetMainWnd();      // <--- CAN RETURN NULL HERE
        hwndTemp->EnableWindow(FALSE);          // <--- CRASH WILL OCCUR HERE
        CPrintingDialog dlgPrintStatus(this);

        CString strTemp;
        dlgPrintStatus.SetDlgItemText(AFX_IDC_PRINT_DOCNAME, strTitle);
        dlgPrintStatus.SetDlgItemText(AFX_IDC_PRINT_PRINTERNAME,
            printInfo.m_pPD->GetDeviceName());
        dlgPrintStatus.SetDlgItemText(AFX_IDC_PRINT_PORTNAME, strPortName);
        dlgPrintStatus.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
        dlgPrintStatus.UpdateWindow();

        // start document printing process
        if (!printInfo.m_bDocObject)
        {
            printInfo.m_nJobNumber = dcPrint.StartDoc(&docInfo);
            if (printInfo.m_nJobNumber == SP_ERROR)
            {
                // enable main window before proceeding
                hwndTemp->EnableWindow(TRUE);

                // cleanup and show error message
                OnEndPrinting(&dcPrint, &printInfo);
                dlgPrintStatus.DestroyWindow();
                dcPrint.Detach();   // will be cleaned up by CPrintInfo destructor
                AfxMessageBox(AFX_IDP_FAILED_TO_START_PRINT);
                return;
            }
        }

        // Guarantee values are in the valid range
        UINT nEndPage = printInfo.GetToPage();
        UINT nStartPage = printInfo.GetFromPage();

        if (nEndPage < printInfo.GetMinPage())
            nEndPage = printInfo.GetMinPage();
        if (nEndPage > printInfo.GetMaxPage())
            nEndPage = printInfo.GetMaxPage();

        if (nStartPage < printInfo.GetMinPage())
            nStartPage = printInfo.GetMinPage();
        if (nStartPage > printInfo.GetMaxPage())
            nStartPage = printInfo.GetMaxPage();

        int nStep = (nEndPage >= nStartPage) ? 1 : -1;
        nEndPage = (nEndPage == 0xffff) ? 0xffff : nEndPage + nStep;

        VERIFY(strTemp.LoadString(AFX_IDS_PRINTPAGENUM));

        // If it's a doc object, we don't loop page-by-page
        // because doc objects don't support that kind of levity.

        BOOL bError = FALSE;
        if (printInfo.m_bDocObject)
        {
            OnPrepareDC(&dcPrint, &printInfo);
            OnPrint(&dcPrint, &printInfo);
        }
        else
        {
            // begin page printing loop
            for (printInfo.m_nCurPage = nStartPage;
                printInfo.m_nCurPage != nEndPage; printInfo.m_nCurPage += nStep)
            {
                OnPrepareDC(&dcPrint, &printInfo);

                // check for end of print
                if (!printInfo.m_bContinuePrinting)
                    break;

                // write current page
                TCHAR szBuf[80];
                ATL_CRT_ERRORCHECK_SPRINTF(_sntprintf_s(szBuf, _countof(szBuf), _countof(szBuf) - 1, strTemp, printInfo.m_nCurPage));

                dlgPrintStatus.SetDlgItemText(AFX_IDC_PRINT_PAGENUM, szBuf);

                // set up drawing rect to entire page (in logical coordinates)
                printInfo.m_rectDraw.SetRect(0, 0,
                    dcPrint.GetDeviceCaps(HORZRES),
                    dcPrint.GetDeviceCaps(VERTRES));
                dcPrint.DPtoLP(&printInfo.m_rectDraw);

                // attempt to start the current page
                if (dcPrint.StartPage() < 0)
                {
                    bError = TRUE;
                    break;
                }

                // must call OnPrepareDC on newer versions of Windows because
                // StartPage now resets the device attributes.
                OnPrepareDC(&dcPrint, &printInfo);

                ASSERT(printInfo.m_bContinuePrinting);

                // page successfully started, so now render the page
                OnPrint(&dcPrint, &printInfo);
                if ((nStep > 0) && // pages are printed in ascending order
                    (nEndPage > printInfo.GetMaxPage() + nStep)) // out off pages
                {
                    // OnPrint may have set the last page
                    // because the end of the document was reached.
                    // The loop must not continue with the next iteration.
                    nEndPage = printInfo.GetMaxPage() + nStep; 
                }

                // If the user restarts the job when it's spooling, all 
                // subsequent calls to EndPage returns < 0. The first time
                // GetLastError returns ERROR_PRINT_CANCELLED
                if (dcPrint.EndPage() < 0 && (GetLastError()!= ERROR_SUCCESS))
                {
                    HANDLE hPrinter;
                    if (!OpenPrinter(LPTSTR(printInfo.m_pPD->GetDeviceName().GetBuffer()), &hPrinter, NULL))
                    {
                        bError = TRUE;
                        break;
                    }

                    DWORD cBytesNeeded;
                    if(!GetJob(hPrinter,printInfo.m_nJobNumber,1,NULL,0,&cBytesNeeded))
                    {
                        if (GetLastError() != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
                        {
                           bError = TRUE;
                           break;
                        }
                    }

                    JOB_INFO_1 *pJobInfo;                   
                    if((pJobInfo = (JOB_INFO_1 *)malloc(cBytesNeeded))== NULL)
                    {
                        bError = TRUE;
                        break;
                    }

                    DWORD cBytesUsed;

                    BOOL bRet = GetJob(hPrinter,printInfo.m_nJobNumber,1,LPBYTE(pJobInfo),cBytesNeeded,&cBytesUsed);

                    DWORD dwJobStatus = pJobInfo->Status;

                    free(pJobInfo);
                    pJobInfo = NULL;

                    // if job status is restart, just continue
                    if(!bRet || !(dwJobStatus & JOB_STATUS_RESTART) )
                    {
                        bError = TRUE;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if(!_AfxAbortProc(dcPrint.m_hDC, 0))
                {       
                    bError = TRUE;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // cleanup document printing process
        if (!printInfo.m_bDocObject)
        {
            if (!bError)
                dcPrint.EndDoc();
            else
                dcPrint.AbortDoc();
        }

        hwndTemp->EnableWindow();    // enable main window

        OnEndPrinting(&dcPrint, &printInfo);    // clean up after printing
        dlgPrintStatus.DestroyWindow();

        dcPrint.Detach();   // will be cleaned up by CPrintInfo destructor
    }
}
```

Comment: Please where did you got the source documentation of "`AfxGetApp()->GetMainWnd();` instead of `AfxGetMainWnd();`"?

Comment: I think from another question about AfxGetMainWnd.  That is where I found out that a reason that it can return null is that it is being called from the wrong thread, which was the clue that ultimately led me to discover that I was also inadvertently calling on the wrong thread.  I don't think it is a good idea in this case, because I think the code would have crashed later if I use it to get the pointer to the main window.   https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7fc83809-f0df-4fd5-b4d8-ddd469ed077c/afxgetmainwnd-return-null?forum=vssmartdevicesnative

Answer (score 2):

source code for `CView::OnFilePrint` should be in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\viewprnt.cpp`, depending on VS version. There could also be a problem with printer initialization/access.

If there is any error it is most likely due to printer initialization. You can override `OnFilePrint` and add `CPrintInfo printInfo` for testing. Example:

```
//ON_COMMAND(ID_FILE_PRINT, &CView::OnFilePrint)
//ON_COMMAND(ID_FILE_PRINT_DIRECT, &CView::OnFilePrint)
ON_COMMAND(ID_FILE_PRINT, OnFilePrint)
ON_COMMAND(ID_FILE_PRINT_DIRECT, OnFilePrint)

void CMyView::OnFilePrint()
{
    try
    {
        CPrintInfo printInfo;
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        //log error
        AfxMessageBox(L"error");
    }

    CView::OnFilePrint();
}
```

As noted in comments, another possibility is that there is a bug somewhere else in the code, which may not necessarily be related to printing.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  I have already added the OnFilePrint to our class, and heavily instrumented it.  I will add a try catch around the CPrintInfo as you have suggested.  We will be testing the code tomorrow at the facility that is having the problem.  I'll report back if/when we get to the bottom of the issue.